# Unexpected identifier - JS Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous

I've the next code in a .js file

```
const { User } = require('../models')

module.exports = {
  async register (req, res) {
    try {
      const user = await User.create(req.body)
      res.send(user.toJSON())
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).send({
        error: 'Email de cuenta ya esta en uso'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

And when i run my node app i get the error

```
  async register (req, res) {
        ^^^^^^^^ 
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I can't realize what i am missing about!

Comment: @jfriend00 could you answer the post clarifying the comment?

Comment: What version of node.js are you running?

Comment: Node: v6.9.5   NPM: v3.10.10

Comment: Per this chart https://node.green/, it does not appear that node version 6.x supports `async` at all.  You would need node v7.10 or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved that updating my node version
from: v6.9.5
to: v8.12.0

I'd to uninstall my old node version (it was on c:/laragon/bin/node, and left which was installed from the node oficial msi installer on c:/program files(x86)/nodejs)

Thanks to @jfriend00 on comments!

Answer (score 1):

```
module.exports = {
  register:  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.create(req.body)
      res.send(user.toJSON())
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).send({
        error: 'Email de cuenta ya esta en uso'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

In case you want do use a class, in the same syntax:

```
module.exports = class MyClass {
  async register(req, res) {
        try {
          const user = await User.create(req.body)
          res.send(user.toJSON())
        } catch (err) {
          res.status(400).send({
            error: 'Email de cuenta ya esta en uso'
          })
        }
  }

}
```

Comment: Is it a new way to write code?, because i was following a tutorial from Freecodecamp.org and he wrote the code such as i wrote in the post

Comment: To add clarification OP is trying to export an object, which requires `key: value` pairs, as shown above.

Comment: So, there is no way that the code i wrote above works?.
 I say that because somethings change in ESM6, etc.

Comment: You could write as you did, but you would need to use a class.

Comment: I edited my code as you did and i get the following error
`Parsing error: unexpected token {` On the line 
 `register: async (req, res) {`

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add other things.

Comment: answer fixed as you can see there.

Comment: Trying the first way i get an **Unexpected token** on the open parenthesis `async (req, res) => {`

On the second way i get the same error like in the post. Uhmm.. i don't know how to procceed